# Ruby on Rails / ActiveRecord: How Can I (Elegantly) Retrieve Data from Multiple Tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It's rather trivial to retrieve data from multiple tables that are related through foreign keys using raw SQL. I can do, for example:

```sql
SELECT title, domestic_sales
FROM movies
  JOIN boxoffice
    ON movies.id = boxoffice.movie_id;
```

This would give me a table with two colums: `title` and `domestic_sales`, where the data in the first column comes from the table `movies` and the data in the second column comes from the table `boxoffice`.

How can I do this in Rails using Ruby code? I can, of course, get the same result if I use raw SQL. So, I could do the following:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(<<-SQL)
SELECT title, domestic_sales
FROM movies
  JOIN boxoffice
    ON movies.id = boxoffice.movie_id;
SQL
```

This would give me a `PG::Result` object with the data I want. But this is super inelegant. I would like to be able to get this information without using raw SQL.

So, this is the first thing that comes to mind is:

```rb
Movie.select(:name, :domestic_sales).joins(:box_office)
```

The problem, however, is that the aforementioned line of code returns a bunch of `Movie` objects. Since the `Movie` class doesn't have the `domestic_sales` attribute, I don't get access to that information.

The next thing I thought was to use a loop. So, I could do something like:

```rb
Movie.joins(:box_office).to_a.map do |m|
    {name: m.name, rating: m.box_office.domestic_sales}
end
```

This gives me exactly the data I want. But it costs n + 1 SQL queries, which is not good. I should be able to get this with just one query...

So: How can I retrieve the data I want without using raw SQL and without using loops that cost multiple queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT title, domestic_sales
FROM movies
  JOIN boxoffice
    ON movies.id = boxoffice.movie_id;
```

translated to `ActiveRecord` would look like this

```
Movie
  .select(:title, :domestice_sales)
  .joins("boxoffice ON movies.id = boxoffice.movie_id")
```

When you have proper associations defined in your models you would would be able to write:

```
Movie
  .select(:title, :domestice_sales)
  .joins(:boxoffices)
```

And when you do not need an instance of `ActiveRecord` and would be fine with a nested array, you can even write:

```
Movie
  .joins(:boxoffices)
  .pluck(:title, :domestice_sales)
```

Comment: Nice, this helps! `Movie.joins(:boxoffices).pluck(:title, :domestic_sales)` gives me exactly the information I want. But `Movie.select(:title, :domestic_sales).joins(:boxoffices)` still just give me a bunch of incomplete `Movie` objects.

Comment: The output from pry is:

```
Movie.select(:name, :domestic_sales).joins(:box_office)
  Movie Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "movies"."name", "domestic_sales" FROM "movies" INNER JOIN "box_offices" ON "box_offices"."movie_id" = "movies"."id"
=> [#<Movie:0x00005575f01b4e30 id: nil, name: "Finding Nemo">,
 #<Movie:0x00005575f01b4cf0 id: nil, name: "Monsters University">,
 #<Movie:0x00005575f01b4bb0 id: nil, name: "Ratatouille">,
```

etc...

Comment: That is true, the instances of Movie are kind of incomplete – and that might lead to dangerous side-effects when you call `update` or `save` on them. But I am pretty sure that the incomplete instance would still return the expected values when calling `title` and `domestice_sales` in them.

Comment: Huh. Interesting. The `Movie` objects that I get actually do return the right info when I call `domestic_sales` in them. I guess I missed this because the `domestic_sales` doesn't show up explicitly in the output. I'm not sure I completely understand how this is working under the hood, but at least now I can see that it's working! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

`Movie.joins(:box_office).pluck(:title, :domestic_sales)`